# Filtrado de datos entre dos tablas SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, sql

Muy buenas tardes, tengo un problema al querer seleccionar datos en específico al hacer una consulta a dos tablas; las tablas son las siguientes:

```
create table persona
(
id int identity (1,1) not null,
nombre varchar (350) not null,
apellido varchar (350) not null,
ci varchar (125) unique not null, --tomando en cuenta el departamento
usuario varchar (250) unique not null,
contrasenia varchar (350) not null,
fechaInicio date not null,
estado varchar (8) not null,
constraint pk_persona primary key (id)
);
create table rol
(
id int identity (1,1) not null,
nombre varchar (350) not null,
persona int not null,
fecha date not null,
constraint pk_rol primary key (id),
constraint fk_rol_persona foreign key (persona)
references persona (id)
);



insert into persona values ('juan', 'perez', '1515', 'jp', '1234', '12/12/2012', 'activo')
insert into persona values ('pedro', 'lopez', '1616', 'pl', '1598', '13/12/2012', 'activo')
insert into rol values ('encargado', 1,'10/05/2018')
insert into rol values ('director', 1,'12/05/2018')
insert into rol values ('encargado', 2,'20/05/2018')
insert into rol values ('encargado', 2,'22/05/2018')
```

La consulta que estuve usando es esta:

```
select p.id, p.nombre, p.apellido, p.ci, p.usuario, p.contrasenia, p.fechaInicio, p.estado, r.nombre , r.fecha as 'fecha rol'
from persona p, rol r where p.id=r.persona
```

El resultado es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que necesito es que me retornen los datos que tienen en base a la última fecha a su rol otorgado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es esto:

```
select  p.id, 
        p.nombre, 
        p.apellido, 
        p.ci, 
        p.usuario, 
        p.contrasenia, 
        p.fechaInicio, 
        p.estado, 
        r.nombre , 
        r.fecha as 'fecha rol'
    from persona p
    -- Ultimo rol por persona
    left join (select persona,
            MAX(fecha) as 'fecha'
            from rol r 
            group by persona
        ) m
        on m.persona=p.id
    left join rol r
        on r.persona = p.id
        and r.fecha = m.fecha
```

Lo fundamental de esta consulta es obtener la fecha del último rol por `persona`, que vendría a ser `MAX(fecha)`, con esta información armamos una subconsulta que nos permite filtrar solamente los roles cuya fecha se la mencionada.

Algunos comentarios:

- Es recomendable usar los `JOIN` explícitos mediante la clausula `ON`
- Usamos `LEFT` simplemente para que se muestren todas las personas, tengan un rol o no, si solo quieres las que tienen algún rol, modifica el `join` por un `INNER`.
- Esta consulta asume que no puede haber fechas repetidas para una misma persona. Es decir, que tenga más de un rol en el mismo período de tiempo.

Comment: Muchas, pero muchísimas gracias ahora si obtiene la tabla como tiene que ser